# Screen flashing between two colors fast enough so not conceivable by the human eye

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, html5-animation

Hi I'm trying to have a flashing screen where the color changes between two colors in WebGL. I have the code setup for a square with one color but couldn't figure how to make it switch between two colors at a speed not conceivable by the human eye, say 1KHz. Thanks in advance, I'm new to this.

Comment: And where is the code you're using?

Comment: The screen refresh rate of a standard computer monitor is at around 100 Hz. Unless you have specialized equipment you can't get to 1KHz.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help us in help you, always provide the relavant parts of the code and http://whathaveyoutried.com .

Comment: If the flashing is so fast it's not detectable by the human eye, why do it?

Comment: @SteveWellens: possibly to implement some form of dithering?

Comment: Oh, incidentally: please don't; all I can really say is that the [effect is nauseous](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JzYkW/1/). (And if you're potentially a photosensitive epileptic **please do not** visit that link.)

Comment: The code im using so far is the code from: learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson02/index.html I'm using the code for the square. I know pople have implemented it using Native, isn't it possible using WebGL? @SteveWellens: There are communication applications for the same. Check out News Flash by MIT for a demo

Comment: @DavidThomas: That is sort of what I'm looking for but could it go any faster so that to the human eye it looks like one constant color

Comment: No; it's down to the refresh rate of the monitor, and its ability to update the display as quickly as JavaScript processes the code. The native ability of a monitor to dither is activated by the requested colour (and it's not being available except with dithering).

Comment: Thanks. The best way to achieve it is keep the blocks fized and flash it using java script. Just found out, so thought i'd share

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible.  Computer monitors don't refresh that quickly.